# searching for calendar extension for TYPO3 (upcoming events, month view, widget)

Tags: php, events, calendar, widget, typo3

I'm searching for a calendar which can be easily embedded on a site (Typo3 / php).

Requirements:

- month view
- widget (small calendar view)
- internationalization
- events should be added

The calendar should show the upcoming events with a detailed view when clicking on it. My problem is to find such a calendar extension, which is also regularly updated/maintaned and easy to integrate. I can create events, when using `mbl_newsevent` but I need the widget in month view. Extensions like `Extended Calendar` or `Calendar Base` don't provide me such a widget view. Also it should support different languages (english, german). What about multiple events on a day or events which intersect (same time)?

So taking a PHP calendar or jQuery calender together with `mbl_newsevent` is my only option? Do you know a solution?

Currently it seems that [PHP Calendar](http://keithdevens.com/software/php_calendar) and `mbl_newsevent` is my best chance for realizing such a project. But it seems that it only supports one event on a day ...

Comment: Did you try yourself an extension? Show us your code?

Comment: No I didn't used an extension. I want to know how I can implement this.